# Justifying data samples are from different distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $x \in \{0,1\}^N$, and

\begin{align}
    D &= \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{M}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

So that $D \in \{0,1\}^{N \times M} $.

This is the original dataset. The zero indicate a trait and 1 indicate absence of the trait. The sequence of the  0's and 1's matter for each $x$.
A new data sample $D'$ was generated using a different generation process (for example Boltzman machine).

I am looking for a test statistic to show  that $D$ and $D'$ are different distributions or otherwise. For example, it would be possible to use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but I am not certain this would be appropriate for the data. Another contending approach is kernel 2 sample test. Again, while this might work I am wondering if there is any caveat.

Or is there any other statistical test that might be more relevant?

References:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88764/test-for-difference-between-2-empirical-discrete-distributions

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204359/method-to-justify-claim-that-two-samples-come-from-the-same-distribution

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/is-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-valid-with-discrete-distributions

Comment: Thank you! Any motivation for this choice?

Comment: the whitney test ranks all the values from low to high ... as far as I know , would this not be problematic given the nature of the data?